# Is there any way to simplify this function in java script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have application made by vue js, so now i have to extend the application and searching for a way to make the code reusable instead of writing separate for each field.
Basically now i have to add many new sections (inputs) with the same logic, but it doesn't make any sense to create new functions for each field.
Is there any way how i can use the new function for any field that will use the same logic? I am thinking about the `toggle`, `search` and `computed` properties.

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-select
            v-model="signalproviders_0"
            :items="signalProviders"
            label="Signal Provider"
            multiple
            :rules="[requiredSignalsProviders]"
        >
            <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
                <v-chip small v-if="index === 0">
                    <span>{{ item.substring(0, 10) }}...</span>
                </v-chip>
                <span
                    v-if="index === 1"
                    class="grey--text text-caption"
                >
                  +{{ signalproviders_0.length - 1 }}
                </span>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:prepend-item>
                <v-list-item>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-text-field v-model="searchSignalProviders_0" placeholder="Search" @input="searchSignalProvidersOne"></v-text-field>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>

                <v-list-item
                    ripple
                    @click="toggleSignalProvidersOne"
                >
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon :color="signalproviders_0.length > 0 ? 'indigo darken-4' : ''">
                            {{ signalProvidersOneIcon }}
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>
                            Select all
                        </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </template>
        </v-select>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Here is script section

```
data: () => ({
  signalProviders: [],
  signalProvidersOneCopy: [],
  signalproviders_0: [],
  searchSignalProviders_0: '',

  categoriesOne: [],
  categoriesOneCopy: [],
  categories_0: [],
  searchCategories_0: '',
}),
methods: {
  async fetchSignalProviders() {}
  async fetchCategories() {}

  toggleSignalProvidersOne () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.selectedAllSignalProviders) {
            this.signalproviders_0 = []
        } else {
            this.signalproviders_0 = this.signalProviders.slice()
        }
    })
  },
  toggleCategoriesOne () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.selectedAllCategories) {
            this.categories_0 = []
        } else {
            this.categories_0 = this.categoriesOne.slice()
        }
    })
  },

  searchCategoriesOne(e) {
    if (!this.searchCategories_0) {
        this.categoriesOne = this.categoriesOneCopy;
    }

    this.categoriesOne = this.categoriesOneCopy.filter((category) => {
        return category.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchCategories_0.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  },
  searchSignalProvidersOne(e) {
    if (!this.searchSignalProviders_0) {
        this.signalProviders = this.signalProvidersOneCopy;
    }

    this.signalProviders = this.signalProvidersOneCopy.filter((item) => {
        return item.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchSignalProviders_0.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  },
},
computed: {
  selectedAllSignalProviders () {
    return this.signalproviders_0.length === this.signalProviders.length
  },
  selectedSomeSignalProviders () {
    return this.signalproviders_0.length > 0 && !this.selectedAllSignalProviders
  },
  signalProvidersOneIcon () {
    if (this.selectedAllSignalProviders) return 'mdi-close-box'
    if (this.selectedSomeSignalProviders) return 'mdi-minus-box'
    return 'mdi-checkbox-blank-outline'
  },
  selectedAllCategories () {
    return this.categories_0.length === this.categoriesOne.length
  },
  selectedSomeCategories () {
    return this.categories_0.length > 0 && !this.selectedAllCategories
  },
  categoriesOneIcon () {
    if (this.selectedAllCategories) return 'mdi-close-box'
    if (this.selectedSomeCategories) return 'mdi-minus-box'
    return 'mdi-checkbox-blank-outline'
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by modified the functions and sending parameters. So one example bellow.

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-select
            v-model="categories_0"
            :items="all_categories_0"
            label="Category"
            multiple
            :rules="[requiredCategories]"
        >
            <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
                <v-chip small v-if="index === 0">
                    <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
                </v-chip>
                <span
                    v-if="index === 1"
                    class="grey--text text-caption"
                >
                  +{{ categories_0.length - 1 }}
                </span>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:prepend-item>
                <v-list-item>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-text-field v-model="search_categories_0" placeholder="Search" @input="search('categories', '0')"></v-text-field>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>

                <v-list-item
                    ripple
                    @click="toggle('categories', '0')"
                >
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon :color="categories_0.length > 0 ? 'indigo darken-4' : ''">
                            {{ icon('categories', '0') }}
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>
                            Select all
                        </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </template>
        </v-select>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Data is defined as...

```
data: () => ({
    all_categories_0: [],
    all_categories_0_copy: [],
    categories_0: [],
    search_categories_0: '',
}),
```

Methods...

```
methods: {
    toggle(data, order) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            if (this.selectedAll(data, order)) {
                this.$data[data + '_' + order] = []
            } else {
                this.$data[data + '_' + order] = this.$data['all_' + data + '_' + order].slice()
            }
        })
    },
    search(data, order) {
        if (!this.$data['search_' + data + '_' + order]) {
            this.$data['all_' + data + '_' + order] = this.$data['all_' + data + '_' + order + '_copy'];
        }
        this.$data['all_' + data + '_' + order] = this.$data['all_' + data + '_' + order + '_copy'].filter((item) => {
            return item.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.$data['search_' + data + '_' + order].toLowerCase()) > -1;
        })
    },
},
```

And finally the computer propertis...

```
computed: {
    selectedAll() {
        return (data, order) => {
            return this.$data[data + '_' + order].length === this.$data['all_' + data + '_' + order].length
        }
    },
    selectedSome() {
        return (data, order) => {
            return this.$data[data + '_' + order].length > 0 && !this.selectedAll(data, order)
        }
    },
    icon() {
        return (data, order) => {
            if (this.selectedAll(data, order)) return 'mdi-close-box'
            if (this.selectedSome(data, order)) return 'mdi-minus-box'
            return 'mdi-checkbox-blank-outline'
        }
    },
},
```